# How to change highlight colour in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 I've set that during debugging the entire line is highlighted but I don't like those dflt colours and I would like to change them. Unfortunately I couldn't find anywere in tools/options where I could be able to do so.
More than greatfull if someone could help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you want but you can make modifications to test font and colors .
Go to Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts&Colors . Select one of the display items
eg .`BreakPoint(error)` and select its foreground and background properties from the dropdowns.